# Do systems of objects over a Grothendieck category form a Grothendieck category?

Tags: ct.category-theory, abelian-categories

Let $\mathscr C$ be a Grothendieck category and let $I$ be a small category (not a preadditive category, just a small category). Is the category $\mathscr C^I$ of systems of objects in $\mathscr C$ indexed over $I$ also a Grothendieck category?

Comment: Yes. This also holds if your indexing category is preadditive and you restrict to additive functors.

Comment: This is in Grothendieck's Tohoku paper. A Grothendieck category is an AB5 abelian category with a generator. Proposition 1.9.2 shows that $C^I$ has a generator. Proposition 1.6.1 shows that $C^I$ is AB5.